# cant find ant-macros.xml when building sample gcm-demo-appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, ant, google-cloud-messaging

When trying to build sample gcm-demo-appengine I get this error.

```
vihaan@cd:~/sourceCode/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-appengine$ ant -Dsdk.dir=/home/vihaan/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9 runserver
Buildfile: /home/vihaan/sourceCode/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-appengine/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/vihaan/sourceCode/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-appengine/build.xml:27: Cannot find /home/vihaan/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9/config/user/ant-macros.xml imported from /home/vihaan/sourceCode/gcm/samples/gcm-demo-appengine/build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I have checked the sdk.dir i.e /home/vihaan/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9 and there is no config folder nor ant-macros.xml file. How and where do I get the ant-macros.xml file from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java , the zip file has the files needed for running it. Don't know whats wrong with eclipse gae plugin.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR ANSWER +1 :)
 I downloaded it but now the error in java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 
do you have an idea what i should do or which version to use? thank you